# mvvmlight navigation upon button click

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, mvvm-light

I have been reading the article by [Laurent Bugnion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx) so that I can understand mvvm. One thing that confused me was just simply how to navigate upon a button click. Laurent talks about the Viewmodel and the view, but how exactly do i navigate to another page upon a button click?

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase {
  private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
  private RelayCommand _navigateCommand;

  private LibraryViewModel _libraryView;
  public LibraryViewModel LibraryView {
     get { return _libraryView; }
     set { _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(LibraryPage)); }
  }
  ...
}
```

**View**

```
<AppBarButton 
  x:Uid="LibraryButton"
  Command="{Binding LibraryView, Mode=TwoWay}"
  Icon="List"/>
```

Comment: You need to bind the Command of the button to an actual command in the viewmodel, not to the view itself (I see you have already declared such a `_navigateCommand`). Then you just need to execute whatever code is necessary to navigate to a different page. There is another article looking a bit closer at commmands btw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx